# what does the linux standard base specify about the kernel?

Tags: linux, standard, lsb

I was taking a look at the Linux standard base (lsb) and could not find much interesting info on the kernel.

Does the LSB specify anything at all about the kernel or kernel interface? Is it kernel agnostic? By interface I mean things like:

- where does a bootloader look for the kernel? How does the bootloader load the kernel?
- system calls
- kernel module API
- proc and sys filesystems. As @jofel mentioned, there has been some [discussion](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/en/LSB_Kernel_Interfaces), but it does not seem to be implemented.

If it did specifies things like that, then it would be possible to plug in different kernels without problem.

Of course, maybe it is too early to thing about those things, since the Linux Kernel dominates LSB systems and sets a de facto standard anyway.

Comment: please downvote explain why. is the question too obvious?

Comment: There was at least some [discussion](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/en/LSB_Kernel_Interfaces) about an LSB kernel interface.

Comment: @jofel cool, that mentions another point which should be standardized: proc and sys filesystems.

Answer (score 1):

I guess boot-loading, since it occurs before an environment is up and running, is outside the scope of the LSB. For system calls, there is this document: [14.3.3. System Calls](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/libc.html#AEN2558). For modules, the only reference I found in the LSB, is about PAM modules (authentification related, very specific), the other use of the word “module” is to designate LSB modules. Then, `/proc` and al, are FHS related (file system hierarchy standard), but the LSB still mentions it as not being mandatory, I guess in case someone don’t find it in the FHS: [Chapter 18. File System Hierarchy](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/LSB_5.0.0/LSB-Core-generic/LSB-Core-generic/execenvfhs.html). It says these may be not present: `etc/X11` `/usr/bin/X11` `/usr/lib/X11` `/proc`. For the other entries in the file system, one may look at the [FHS](https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/fhs).